# Expand the EpandableListView when a button is clicked

Tags: android, onclick, expandablelistview

I'm trying to implement exapndablelistview in my project. I'm able to expand the listView, the problem is i just want to expand it only when i click on the image, but the list is expanded  whenever I click anywhere on the listview row.
Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

my code in xml is

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent">
   </ExpandableListView>
```

and my java class is

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity{
    TextView tv;
    ExpandableListView lv;
    Button b1;
     Integer imgk[]={R.drawable.dhoni,R.drawable.ganguly,R.drawable.irfan,R.drawable.rahul,R.drawable.sachin,R.drawable.sehwag,R.drawable.singh,R.drawable.sri,R.drawable.uthapa,R.drawable.yuvi};
    String[] names={"MS Dhoni","Sorav Ganguly","Irfan Pathan","Rahul Dravid","Sachin Tendulkar","Virender Sehwag","Harbajan Singh","Sreeshanth","Robin Uthapa","Yuvraj Singh"};
    String matches[]={"21","12","13","15","35","22","25","18","21","31"};
    String[] fifty={"12","21","16","10","16","18","10","20","19","22"};
    String hund[]={"21","12","17","18","13","21","23","10","21","14"};
    String[] team={"India","pakistan","bangladesh","australia","new zealand","south Africa","england","zimbabwe","west indies","sri lanka"};
    String[][] childs={{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"},{"India","pakistan"}};
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);

        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        tv.setSelected(true); 

        lv=getExpandableListView();

    CustomAdapter ca=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        lv.setAdapter(ca);
    }





  public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
     Context con;
     private LayoutInflater myInflater;
     private Bitmap bm;
     int count=0;
    public CustomAdapter(Context con) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.con=con;
        myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(con);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childs[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return names[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childs[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
          if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatexml, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();

           holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

           holder.img=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
           holder.img1= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
           holder.down=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
          } 
          else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

          holder.txtName.setText(names[groupPosition]);
          holder.img.setImageResource(imgk[groupPosition]);


            holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(),
                        imgk[groupPosition]);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);   
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
                    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Details.class);
                    in.putExtra("img", b);
                    in.putExtra("names", names[groupPosition]);
                    in.putExtra("matches", matches[groupPosition]);
                    in.putExtra("fifty", fifty[groupPosition]);
                    in.putExtra("hund", hund[groupPosition]);
                    in.putExtra("team", team[groupPosition]);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
            holder.down.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    count++;
                    if(isExpanded){
                        holder.down.setFocusable(false);
                        lv.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        System.out.println("collapsed.....");
                    }

                    else{
                        holder.down.setFocusable(false);
                        lv.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                        System.out.println("Expanded.....");
                    }
                }
            });

          return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv=getGenericView();
        tv.setText(""+childs[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        return tv;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
  static class ViewHolder {
      TextView txtName;
      ImageView img,img1,down;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand/collapse group by clicking on specific Button or some other View, you have to get that Button in getGroupView method in your Adapter class. Then, in onClick method of your Button you have, either to cast parent to ExpandableListView, or to pass List's reference in constructor when you create adapter.

I prefer the first approach. Here's the code, assuming that you have one TextView and an ImageView that is the arrow. I've added changing the arrow state too.
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

```
String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.left_drawer_list_group, parent, false);
}

TextView listHeaderText = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.left_menu_list_header_text);
ImageView listHeaderArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.left_menu_list_header_arrow);

listHeaderText.setText(headerTitle);

//Set the arrow programatically, so we can control it
int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float : android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float;
listHeaderArrow.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

listHeaderArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(isExpanded) ((ExpandableListView) parent).collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        else ((ExpandableListView) parent).expandGroup(groupPosition, true);

    }
});

return convertView;
```

}